# Firebase Authentication code issue (Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm super new to Swift, but I managed to write this code from a few tutorials. Basically it's an authentication setup, but it appears no matter what you put into the username and password inputs (even if it doesn't match the auth details in Firebase) it will still allow you to move on on to the "LoginSuccess" segue. Help!
It was working 100% earlier today, and for some reason it has completely stopped functioning. Here's what I've got in my ViewController.swift file.

PS. this is just a login setup, I do not want people to be able to register.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var SignInLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var UsernameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var SignInButton: UIButton!



var isSignIn:Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func SignInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let user = UsernameTextField.text, let pass = 
PasswordTextField.text {

        // Check if it's sign in or register
        if isSignIn {
            // Sign in with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pass) { 
(user, error) in
                    // User is found, go to home screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", 
sender: self)
                }
        }
    }
                else {
                    // Error: Show alert and clear text entries
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Error", 
message:"Your username or password was incorrect.", 
preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Retry",style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil))

                    self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
                    self.UsernameTextField.text = ""
                    self.PasswordTextField.text = ""
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check errors before `performSegue`

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pass) { (user, error) in
   if error != nil {
      // show error with error.localizedDescription
      return
   }
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess",sender: self)
}
```

Comment: No luck :(
 Still presents home page no matter what

Comment: @Aaron you seem to hook the segue to the button action , so remove it and hook the source of segue to the vc itself

Comment: Very sorry, how would I do that?

Comment: @Aaron select the current segue line and press delete , then drag from the yellow circle top of the vc to the destination and select show , then give it the identfier **loginSuccess**

Comment: I think that worked, it does show the segue eventually but it takes a while now. Another problem is that it appears to skip my entire "error" alert if the password or username is wrong... I'm sorry about this

Comment: track with print statement note **return** inside if statement , the long time as it's asynchronous call you may show activity indicator until recieve any response

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to get it to work with your help.